# How to use a java Hashmap as variable in JasperReport

Tags: java, dictionary, jasper-reports

I want  to use a `java.util.HashMap` as variable in JasperReport to save group names of my report in it.

I have tired and declared a variable of type `java.util.HashMap` and its expression field is:

```
$V{variable1}.put($F{GROUPCOLUMNVALUE}, $F{GROUPCOLUMNVALUE})
```

but it does not works and gives `null` when I print it on report's group footer.

I am using iReport 3.7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote that
Variable expression: `new java.util.HashMap()`
I think it might be `initial value expression` instead of variable expression

Answer (score 1):

I tried it there and got it working.

I set the following properties on the variable:

- Variable class: `java.util.HashMap()`
- Reset type: `None`
- Calculation: `System`
- Variable expression: `new java.util.HashMap()`