# Initialize a HashMap Variable in iReport

Tags: java, groovy, hashmap, jasper-reports, ireport

I want to create a variable $V{myMap} in iReport (3.7.3) and initialize a Map with this:

```
"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3:"value3" ...
```

Then in my report I will have a textField with this expression:

```
$V{myMap}.get("key1")
```

and i must to get

```
"value1"
```

What steps i must to follow to get that?

---

I read here:

[How to use a java Hashmap as variable in JasperReport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439524/i-want-to-use-java-util-hashmap-as-variable-in-jasperreport)

these steps to set the variable properties:

set the following properties on the variable:

```
Name: myMap
Variable class: java.util.HashMap()
Reset type: None
Calculation: System
Variable expression: new java.util.HashMap()
```

But what about initialize it?

I know i can use groovy and use maps like in this article:

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Collections

But i dont' know which steps to follow.

Thanks in advance for share your knowledge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the method to create the variable

```
<variable name="myMap" class="java.util.HashMap" resetType="None" calculation="System">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[['key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2', 'key3':'value3']]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

Then for use it:

```
$V{myMap}.get("key1")
```

Will get

```
value1
```

Comment: In iReport 5.6.0, `java.util.HashMap` is not selectable as variable's type but you can manually insert it. In the "variable expressione" insert `["key1":"value1","key2":"value2"]`. This solution still work fine

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create a singleton, immutable map, with a single entry, you can use Collections.singletonMap():

```
<variable name="hints" class="java.util.Map">
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[Collections.singletonMap("key", "value")]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

To get the value:

```
$V{hints}.get("key")
```

Answer (score -1):

I would try using the property `initial value expresion` and trying to inicialize the hashmap using something like:

```
new HashMap<String , String>() {{
put(stringkey1, stringvalue1);
put(stringkey2, stringvalue2);
put(stringkey3, stringvalue3);
}};
```